# C# Edit documents array in bulk (MongoDb)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following document in MongoDb, where I want sometimes to edit the teams array fields based on an id provided.

```
{
  "_id": "a3e8d0c5-eea6-4d70-bdd9-e97bb5153840",
  "first_name": "test",
  "last_name": "user",
  "email": "usertochangelocal@exampleemail.com",
  "_xid": "",
  "active": true,
  "is_technical_user": false,
  "organisation": {
    "_xid": "eced14e5-1a7a-4b53-9576-d282af45dfc8",
    "name": "companyNameTestlocal",
    "type": "broker"
  },
  "teams": [
    {
      "_id": "3b4193b9-a636-4d38-a3f4-02c9b41d36ee",
      "_xid": "902fce17-f4cb-4383-94d1-d977cc4a6ba5",
      "name": "team1",
      "role": "placing_broker",
      "team_status": "active",
      "membership_active": true,
      "company_xid": "398d1f63-2048-40c4-b596-1d603c5baf03",
      "branch_xid": "9cc8efa2-1b6b-43a0-8f3f-7969f7d40958",
      "company_name": "Company 1",
      "branch_name": "branchtest"
    },
    {
      "_id": "911fca09-125d-42e6-afb7-0cfe41eaf767",
      "_xid": "1dd531c9-3557-49a6-a72b-0cf1ebc4734f",
      "name": "team2",
      "role": "monitored_placing_broker",
      "team_status": "active",
      "membership_active": true,
      "company_xid": "398d1f63-2048-40c4-b596-1d603c5baf03",
      "branch_xid": "9cc8efa2-1b6b-43a0-8f3f-7969f7d40958",
      "company_name": "Company 1",
      "branch_name": "branchtest"
    },
    {
      "_id": "88ce7bfd-3175-49da-8d37-c3cc0f4c32e4",
      "_xid": "dd391e1d-debb-4763-a2c9-5e8c676f0cb5",
      "name": "team1two",
      "role": "placing_broker_team_lead_and_approver",
      "team_status": "active",
      "membership_active": true,
      "company_xid": "cd39aaf9-2971-4d77-a4b5-0ef812c9baeb",
      "branch_xid": "004236d0-988d-4931-a47f-c16bd4afc4a4",
      "company_name": "Company 2",
      "branch_name": "branchtest"
    },
    {
      "_id": "fb5193e6-58da-42b2-a8ae-2ca76fd59758",
      "_xid": "5d1ee688-63ab-4282-bc91-1ab48ed29dcf",
      "name": "teamtwo2",
      "role": "broker_admin_with_markets",
      "team_status": "active",
      "membership_active": true,
      "company_xid": "cd39aaf9-2971-4d77-a4b5-0ef812c9baeb",
      "branch_xid": "004236d0-988d-4931-a47f-c16bd4afc4a4",
      "company_name": "Company 2",
      "branch_name": "branchtest"
    }
  ],
  "default_team": {
    "_xid": "902fce17-f4cb-4383-94d1-d977cc4a6ba5",
    "name": "team1"
  }
}
```

My problem is that, for example, when I edit a company_name, only one of the arrays is being populated.

I've also tried changing the following line of code to this, but this only results on all documents being edited, ignoring the filter:

`var update = Builders<User>.Update.Set($"teams.$[]." + field, value);`

Code:

```
public async Task BulkUpdateTeamMembershipFields((string field, object value) updateFilter, IEnumerable<(string field, object value)> updateFields)
{
    var listWrites = new List<WriteModel<User>>();

    var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("teams." + updateFilter.field, updateFilter.value) &
        Builders<User>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Teams, Builders<UserTeamMembership>.Filter.Eq(updateFilter.field, updateFilter.value));

    foreach (var (field, value) in updateFields)
    {

        var update = Builders<User>.Update.Set($"teams.$." + field, value);

        listWrites.Add(new UpdateManyModel<User>(filter, update));

    }

    if (listWrites.Any())
    {
        var collection = _mongoDb.GetCollection<User>(CollectionNames.Users);

        await collection.BulkWriteAsync(CurrentSession, listWrites);
    }
}
```

Any toughts on this?

Thanks!